# Advanced C# framework with plugins and introspect share assembly information

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection, frameworks, introspection

I'm planning a flexible C# software platform where different vendors can contribute and add features to the host application.
The plugins would extend the host application with additional features (all initialized from the host application).

Let's play with this scenario:
My host application with vendor A's plugin is running fine.
Vendor B see that he would like to inherit a class and override a method / add a method or add properties to add a new class and present that to my host application.

I would like to present assembly information (contract) to vendor B without sending them sourcecode or disassembly existing dll’s.
If I added introspect export function in my host application that some how sourced all the information from my host application and all installed plugins and provided this to Vendor B.
Vendor B could build his plugin and use intellisense in his IDE when writing sourcecode for his new plugin.
How to implement this ??

I use a Java8 framework that work like this and would like to do the same in C#